# NHibernate via Nuget

Tags: nhibernate, orm, nuget

Does anyone know of a good tutorial that covers getting NHibernate up and running via Nuget? I've found a few but they feel incomplete.

Comment: http://gurustop.net/blog/2011/03/13/nhibernate-3-1-0-on-nuget-important-details/

Comment: You know, I looked at that one the other day. I guess since it has been suggested to me twice now I'll follow through with it. Thanks!

Comment: Well it seems the NHibernate package on Nuget has been updated and is version 3.1 which includes pretty much everything you need to get started. I ended up installing NHibernate via Nuget and following the tutorial on http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.aspx and have had good success thus far.

Comment: it would help to know what sort of app your want to plug NHibernate into.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a post about it on my blog:

[NHibernate: Getting started guide(Nuget, NHibernate mapping by code, SQLite)](https://gergroen.blogspot.com/2020/09/nhibernate-getting-started-guide.html)